# EF6 navigation property has kind None but is expected to be of kind Navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a strange issue with an ASP.Net MVC web application where the table relationships in the EF6 entity complains about the navigation link between two tables being of kind "None" whereas it is expected to be of kind "Navigation". The scenario is two SQL tables, one called "User" and one called "Band" which have a navigation link between a "UserID" field in Band and an "Id" field in User. When I publish the web application up to Azure it will, on occasion, error out with the below which seems to imply that it can't find the navigation link between the two tables.
The Band table is queried first and then the related item in the User table is searched for. In the case of the item in the Band table not being found there is no error triggered, only when it finds an item in Band and then tries to search in User does it fall over. A previous release of the software which functions correctly was build on .Net 4.6 with OData version 5.8.3. This version is .Net 4.8 and OData 5.8.5.
The problem is intermittent and seems to only occur at the point the web application starts up. Has anyone come across anything similar? All the evidence seems to point at either the .Net upgrade and/or the OData package upgrade being the cause of the issue.

```html
Microsoft.Data.OData.ReaderValidationUtils.ValidateNavigationPropertyDefined(String propertyName, IEdmEntityType owningEntityType, ODataMessageReaderSettings messageReaderSettings) +201
   Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.TryReadNavigationLinkInEntry(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState, String linkRelation, String linkHRef) +151
   Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadAtomLinkElementInEntry(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState) +214
   Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadAtomElementInEntry(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState) +367
   Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadEntryContent(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState) +95
   Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomReader.ReadEntryStart() +697
   Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomReader.ReadAtFeedStartImplementation() +79
   Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation() +56
   Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadSynchronously() +5
   Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException(Func`1 action) +94
   Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.Read() +68
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderWrapper.Read() +18
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryRead() +30

[InvalidOperationException: A property with name &#39;User&#39; on type &#39;########.Band&#39; has kind &#39;None&#39;, but it is expected to be of kind &#39;Navigation&#39;.]
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryRead() +145
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryStartReadFeedOrEntry() +13
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.TryReadEntry(MaterializerEntry&amp; entry) +15
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.&lt;LazyReadEntries&gt;d__0.MoveNext() +41
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.FeedAndEntryMaterializerAdapter.Read() +29
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataReaderEntityMaterializer.ReadNextFeedOrEntry() +10
   System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataEntityMaterializer.ReadImplementation() +72
   System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNextInternal() +348
   System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom.MoveNext() +68
   System.Linq.&lt;CastIterator&gt;d__97`1.MoveNext() +85
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +183
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton(Expression expression) +305
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +70
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +211
   ActiCheck.IISHandler1.ProcessRequest(HttpContext Context) in C:\Users\############\MsgCoordinator.cs:545
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +813
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously) +73
</pre>                      </code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>

500 Internal Server Error <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I have exactly the same error as you have, also using Odata packages version 5.8.5. Could you ever fix this or still using 5.8.3 instead?

Comment: We're still using 5.8.3 at the moment until a version comes along which we can be sure doesn't cause the issue. It's not causing us any problems using 5.8.3 so we will likely leave as is until a problem does arise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess there will never be a newer version (unless you update to ODATA v4) as mentioned on nuget.org